# Dynamic Library for each controller in angularjs

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

How to include Dynamic Library for each controller in `angularjs` using two controllers in one angular module?

```
For One controller I need to add the header Lib script 
<script src="js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>

for another controller i need to add the header Lib Script Like
<script src="js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

For every  Controller call , Lib  should change automatically.
```

Comment: Can you explain why you would want this behaviour?

Comment: Some of the functionalities missing on each other.for chat module it requires one lib file and other module requires second lib file .Both the lib files has full different functions

Comment: Ok, just confused me you used the same lib in your example. Still, normally you would just have all the required libs loaded.

Answer (score 0):

use `$oclazyload` for loading JS on demand for each controller

This is how you should use it

```
  .state('login', {
       url: '/login',
       controller: 'LoginCtrl',
       templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
       resolve: {
           loadMyFiles: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
               return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                   name: 'APP',
                   files: [
                   'scripts/controller/login.js'
                   ]
               })
           }
       }
   }

)
```

Comment: you are welcome ,if this help you then please mark as answer and upvote so other can refer to this.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is relatively small and straight forward and is generated or provided by some trusted source then you can use `eval` to execute it or do something like this:

```
var jS = document.createElement('script');
jS.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
jS.appendChild(document.createTextNode('console.log("Hello world")'));
document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(jS);
```

But if this does not suit you, you can dynamically create and remove `script` elements and add it or remove it anywhere in your dom.

To create:

```
var jS = document.createElement('script');
jS.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
jS.setAttribute('src', 'lib/ionic/ionic.bundle.js');
// And append this to the end of the head or body tag
```

And when you need to remove this script element

```
document.querySelector("head script[src='lib/ionic/ionic.js']").removeChild()
```